# On a AWS Lightsail Bitnami wordpress server how do I enable ipv6 for https after enabling it for only ipv4 using the bncert-tool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, wordpress, ipv6, bitnami

On my server on AWS Lightsail I installed Wordpress via Bitnami, I then ran the `bncert-tool` via this link https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/generate-install-lets-encrypt-ssl/ but it only works on ipv4 addresses on apache and such, I have done this part 100% fine, but I had to disable ipV6 in the process on my server.

So my question can I just reenable ipv6 on my server and https will continue to work? Or do I need to do some other type of configuration? If so what exactly as I am a bit stuck going forwards... do I even need to enable ipv6? I plan on eventually scaling my site to have a lot of traffic.

Comment: I don't see what enabling IPv6 would be a problem. If you expect a lot of traffic you should look at one of the patterns that allows Wordpress to scale, for example autoscaling the front end web server, using an RDS database, and having a shared file system for the wp-content folder

Comment: thanks for the information

Comment: Please answer your own question if it works, or let us know if you need more help.

Comment: Honestly I deleted the server as found an alternative service so I am not sure if it works anymore but feel free to put your comment as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling IPv6 will not impact https. The IP protocol is layer three (I think), https is layer seven of the OSI stack, layer seven makes use of whichever layer three protocol is used.